# Replace symbol of dynamic loaded library in Linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm trying the PwnAdventure3 CTF and kind of stuck in my solution to hack the game.

Basically, the PwnAdventure3 client loads a library called libGameLogic.so. What I did, was to write my own libGameLogic.so and injected it to the running process. Now, what I would like to do, is to replace an existing function by the one I wrote in my library. To do so, I use dlsym a lot, but I get a segfault when I replace the symbol and I don't know what else to look for. Basically I don't know why it crashes...

The goad is to replace the Player::SetJumpState(bool state) to the one I wrote in my library as it is used in the ClientWorld *GameWorld object.
Here is what the loaded library does when being loaded into the game process :

```
#include "libGameLogic.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <link.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" ClientWorld *GameWorld;


void loadMsg(void)
{
    printf("libGameLogic.so patcher loaded !\n");
}

void Player::SetJumpState(bool state)
{
    printf("Function got replaced !\n");
}

int libraryCallback(struct dl_phdr_info* info, size_t size, void* data) {
    const char* libraryName = "/home/liwinux/Downloads/PwnAdventure3/PwnAdventure3/Binaries/Linux/libGameLogic.so";  // Replace with the name of the original library
    if (strcmp(info->dlpi_name, libraryName) == 0) {
        *(void**)data = dlopen(libraryName, RTLD_LAZY);
        return 1;  // Stop iterating after finding the desired library
    }
    return 0;  // Continue iterating
}

__attribute__((constructor))
void initSharedLib()
{
    
    loadMsg();
    void* handle = nullptr;
    dl_iterate_phdr(libraryCallback, &handle);
    if (!handle) {
        // Handle error if the library handle is not found
        std::cerr << "Failed to find the library handle." << std::endl;
        // Cleanup and return or handle the error accordingly
        return;
    }
    printf("Address of the handle : %p\n", handle);

    void* symbolAddress = dlsym(handle, "_ZThn168_N6Player12SetJumpStateEb");
    printf("Symbol address is : %p\n", symbolAddress);
    if (!symbolAddress)
    {
        // Handle error if symbol is not found
        std::cerr << "Failed to find the symbol: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
        dlclose(handle);
        return;
    }
    if (dlclose(handle) != 0){
        std::cerr << "Failed to close the dyn lib !: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
    }

    void* replacementHandle = dlopen("/home/liwinux/Desktop/pwnie_island/cheat/libGameLogic.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!replacementHandle) {
        // Handle error if the replacement library fails to load
        std::cerr << "Failed to load the replacement library: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
        // Cleanup and return or handle the error accordingly
        return;
    }
    printf("Address of the replacement handle : %p\n", replacementHandle);

    void* replacementSymbolAddress = dlsym(replacementHandle, "_ZN6Player12SetJumpStateEb");
    if (!replacementSymbolAddress) {
        // Handle error if the replacement symbol is not found
        std::cerr << "Failed to find the replacement symbol: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
        dlclose(replacementHandle);
        // Cleanup and return or handle the error accordingly
        return;
    }
    printf("Address of the replacement Symbol : %p\n", replacementSymbolAddress);
    printf("Other : %p\n", *(void**)symbolAddress);
    *(void **)symbolAddress = replacementSymbolAddress;
    printf("All Good !\n");

    
}
```

Of course, I would like the avoid the LD_PRELOAD trick if possible. Could someone enlighten me ? Thank you

Comment: Code-segments are usually read-only, so trying to write into them causes segmentation fault.